# Excel DropDown List Dynamic Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am working on an Excel spreadsheet where we have a formula fetching some text as a comma-separated text like:

[image]

Now, I would like to show this comma-separated text as a dropdown list on the screen as:

[image]

Any way to do this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, use `TEXTSPLIT()` function in a blank cell as a helper column and then use that list in the data validation.

Comment: Using TEXTSPLIT in a column would spill the data into multiple rows, but for each row, we have such lists with dropdowns. So can't really use that option.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have few more data in the below cells delimited like the one in cell A1, if yes, yes you can still do it, like i have said. you cannot use a delimited values in a data validation and use as a dropdown. You need to apply the formula in another column and then use that column as a list for the data validation.

Comment: You can TEXTSPLIT to both rows and columns by choosing to use 2nd or 3rd formula parameter. TEXTSPLIT(A1,,",") or TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")

Comment: @MacAnk if you store a spill formula in let say `C1` you can refer to the spill range as `C1#`. That's what Mayukh means. The additional `#` to the cell value means the whole spill-array.